# Is there any way to add an Event Listener to a class?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a web hosted game, and I am trying to add an event to a class.

I couldn't really find some helpful info on the web, and I tried to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class").addEventListener("click", function(){…});
```

I want it to test if a certain item in a class is clicked but it keeps making an error like this - BattleMode.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at BattleMode.js:4; if I try to do anything else it does not sense the div with the certain properties.

Comment: "A class" is not something that exists in the way your code assumes. That method returns a *list* of elements, and you have to treat them individually. Alternatively, you can use event delegation via event handlers on the `document` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Just remember that `getElementsByClassName()` is plural - Element**s**:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class");

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(){…});
}
```

Note that `getElementsByClassName()` does not return an array. Instead it returns a NodeList which is an array-like object. So the usual array methods like `.map()`, `.forEach()` etc. are not available. NodeLists do have a `.length` property so you can iterate over them.

You can however convert them to arrays using `Array.from` or `slice()`:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("class"))
    .forEach(function(element){
        element.addEventListener("click", function(){…});
    });
```